# AngularJS manipulate data

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a API reader but I am having trouble manipulating data.

for example:

Raw data for this is: "radiant_win":true,  and I want to make it check if true, it will make "Radiant wins" but if its false, it will make "Dire wins" on my index.html.

On top of that, I want to also manipulate the match["duration"] to be split in XX:XX format.

```
<ul class="list">
<li class="item" ng-repeat="match in matches">
    MatchID: {{ match["match_id"] }} 
    Who won: {{ match["radiant_win"]}}
    Time: {{ match["duration"] }}
    Game Mode: {{ match["game_mode"] }}
</li>
```

So it would be like:

Who won: Radiant, Time: 26:25

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please elaborate you question?

Answer (score 0):

To show different content, you need `ng-show`/`ng-hide` or `ng-if`

```
<li class="item" ng-repeat="match in matches">
    MatchID: {{ match["match_id"] }} 
    Who won: <span ng-show="match.radiant_win">Radiant wins</span>
        <span ng-show="!match.radiant_win">Dire wins</span>
    Time: {{ match["duration"] }}
    Game Mode: {{ match["game_mode"] }}
</li>
```

(Or you can use `ng-switch`)

**UPDATE:**

Time format would need some function (in your controller) like this:

```
$scope.format = function(time) {
  time = ""+time; // casting a string 
  let three = time.length == 3;
  let minutes = three ? time.substring(0,1) : time.substring(0,2);
  let seconds = three ? time.substring(1) : time.substring(2);
  return ""+minutes+":"+seconds;
};
```

HTML changes only: `Time: {{ format(match["duration"]) }}`

Comment: {"match_id":3573601133,"player_slot":3,"radiant_win":true,"duration":2500,"game_mode":22,"lobby_type":7} on the duration, I want to split it in two like "25:00"